# Python Snappy is already installed, as part of zip deployed but throws error on AWS lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, snappy

We are using Python 3.9 and installed the package "python-snappy" The code works fine in decompressing avro format on local. However - AWS lambda throws following error:
[ERROR] valueError: snappy codec is supported but you need to install python-snappy.

I faced same error on local before installing python-snappy but after installing the package, the error is resolved. I zipped the same package on local including python snappy and deployed on AWS lambda

Tried manual deployment
automatic deployment using terraform with requirements.txt

Answer (score 0):

It could be differences between the runtime environment of the local machine and the AWS Lambda Runtime environment.

Assuming that the runtime is different. Have you tried using AWS SAM with --use-container option? The dependencies will be build to suit the target AWS Lambda Runtime.